# Apple private API rejection with libarchive

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm using [libarchive](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/) and I have included the source and headers in my iphone project.  Apple rejected the binary saying I've wrongfully used private APIs for a bunch of functions.  One such functions is:

```
archive_read_data
```

How am I wrong? I want to keep my code because it works well but I also want a speedy acceptance. How do I solve this dilemma?

PS they are not responding to my cordial emails.

Comment: Is it possible that Apple has APIs with the same names, and their naive filter is thinking that you're calling their private APIs with those names rather than your own APIs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for your favourite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since libarchive is free software, the easiest solution would probably just be to change the name of that function to something that doesn't trigger false alarms.

Comment: Any word on if this solution has worked? It seems scary that Apple would filter on *names* and not actual linked functions.

Comment: @vicvicvic: I honestly have no clue about the current state of Apple's tools. Problems with the process appear and disappear all the time (e.g. lately I've heard about a lot of Mac apps getting rejected for sandbox violations they weren't actually committing). I've said Apple's screening process was fundamentally stupid from the get-go, and I still think that's the case (though it has improved somewhat), but it's really their way or the highway.

Answer (score 1):

libarchive exists as a dynamic library on iOS. Did you try and remove your static implementation and instead link with the dynamic library?