# Cocoa class for TAR archiving and unarchiving files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Has someone written a simple Cocoa wrapper class around tar archiving/unarchiving of files?

I plan on doing it myself, unless someone out there has graciously already done it.

EDIT: Are there any reasons I shouldn't just write a wrapper class around the "tar" terminal command? (via NSTask)? Unless there are any objections, this is what I now plan on doing.

Comment: Reason: I have some troubles with the terminal tar via NSTask in a sandboxed app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing it (at least the unarchiving, that is) yourself I'd recommend taking a look at [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html)'s source.
It supports Zip, Tar-GZip, Tar-BZip2, RAR, 7-zip, LhA, StuffIt, etc.

---

Alternatively for full archiving/unarchiving support there is **libarchive**,
which is BSD licensed and written in C: http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/
(There even is a [**static library**](https://github.com/davepeck/iOS-libarchive) fork of **libarchive** for use in **iOS**)

> **Filter Support**
>
> - gzip (read and write, uses zlib)
> - bzip2 (read and write, uses bzlib)
> - compress (read and write, uses an internal implementation)
> - uudecode (read only)
> - separate command-line compressors with fixed-signature auto-detection
> - xz and lzma (read and write using liblzma)
> - lzma (if you lack liblzma, you can get read-only lzma support through the
>     lzmadec library; this will likely be
>     dropped as soon as liblzma is stable
>     and widely-available)
> - Starting with libarchive 2.7, most of the above will fall back to using
>     command-line tools if the libraries
>     were unavailable at build time. Note
>     that the command-line tools are
>     usually slower than using the
>     libraries directly.
>
> **Archive Formats Supported**
>
> - tar (read and write, including GNU extensions)
> - pax (read and write, including GNU and star extensions)
> - cpio (read and write, including odc and newc variants)
> - ISO9660 (read only, including Joliet and Rockridge extensions, with
>     some limitations; write support
>     starting with libarchive 2.9)
> - Zip (read only, with some limitations, uses zlib; write support
>     starting with libarchive 2.8)
> - mtree (read and write, uses OpenSSL libraries for creating and verifying
>     cryptographic hashes)
> - shar (write only)
> - ar (read and write, including BSD and GNU/SysV variants)
> - empty (read only; in particular, note that no other format will accept
>     an empty file)
> - raw (read only, starting in libarchive 2.8)
> - xar (read only, starting in libarchive 2.8)

Just for the record: [Apple private API rejection with libarchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507684/apple-private-api-rejection-with-libarchive) (question was solved, btw)

Comment: Well, I need to archive as well as unarchive. Plus the license of those codes aren't really too flexible. See update to the question.

Comment: @Enchilada: uh, you're right. In this case you might want to give **libarchive** a try. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, libarchive is probably the best solution. However, for now I'm gonna go with simulating tarring by running 'tar' via NSTask. I might later revisit libarchive. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used this. It worked for me...
http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/detail?name=ZipArchive.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: Well, I need only archiving, no compression... See update to question.