# How to send a file hierarchy over a socket

Tags: objective-c, file, sockets, recursion

So I am writing an application which will need to receive a file structure over a socket from a server application (which I also have control over). My client is in objective-c and will need to construct an array of "File" objects. I figured that recursion would be a good way to go about this but I know that my implementation is incorrect.

Here is my original thinking:

I was planning on using a syntax to tell the client whether a node had any children (e.g folder) or it was a leaf (e.g file). I also thought of having a "lastleaf" syntax for the last leaf to stop the recursion. The syntax would be "type:path/to/file". Here is the rough algorithm that I came up with:

```
NSString* string = [self getStringFromSocket];
NSArray* split = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

if( [@"lastleaf" isEqualToString:[split objectAtIndex:0]] ) {
    MyFile* newFile = [[MyFile alloc] initWithPath:[split subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [split count]-1)]];
    return [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:newFile, nil];
} else if([@"leaf" isEqualToString:[split objectAtIndex:0]]) {
    MyFile* newFile = [[MyFile alloc] initWithPath:[split subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [split count]-1)]];
    NSMutableArray* children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:newFile, nil];
    [children addObjectsFromArray: [self getFiles]];
    return children;
} else if([@"parent" isEqualToString:[split objectAtIndex:0]]) {
    MyFile* newFile = [[MyFile alloc] initWithPath:[split subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [split count]-1)]];
    [newFile setSubfiles: [self getFiles]];
    return [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:newFile, nil];
}
```

}

I'm happy for anyone to ignore this and to deal with pseudo-code, it was just my flawed thinking of doing things.

I would appreciate any suggestions or help.

**Edit: I only want to see the path of the files and their structure, not the contents**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perfect way to encapsulate a filesystem structure is with nested `NSDictionary` objects:

- There's no chance of infinite recursion because there's a finite number of key-value pairs
- If you want to add attributes to the files you can use a key syntax like `<filename>_attr_readonly` or `<filename>_isFolder`, or you can even provide a `serialize` and `deserialize` function on custom `File` objects (containing the attributes and so forth) which convert them into `NSString`s, and use those strings as the corresponding value to the filename key
- These can be serialized natively to a Plist file, and then you send the plist to the client (with compression, which will work extra well due to the content being text only)

To be slightly clearer:

```
NSDictionary (path: "/")
|
*-- key "myFile" -> value <MyFile> (path: "/myFile")
|
*-- key "myNestedFolder" -> value <NSDictionary>
                                   |
                                   *-- key "myNestedFile" -> value <MyFile>
                                       (path "/myNestedFolder/myNestedFile")
```

Comment: I found this way the easiest to implement and it makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would send it in ZIP format. Takes care of the entire protocol issue and also adds compression. All you need is a suitable library.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should leverage an existing class or library that manipulates file archive. That will have all the logic necessary for bundling together a file hierarchy and for unpacking it. Check this question for more info [Cocoa class for TAR archiving and unarchiving files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179978/cocoa-class-for-tar-archiving-and-unarchiving-files)

Comment: Note that I only want to send the **list** of files, not the contents of them. Does this answer still apply? I've updated the question.